# Shopify GDPR Webhooks don't trigger

Tags: shopify, webhooks

I created a Shopify app and I want to test GDPR Webhooks. One of them (customer data request) is working fine, but 2 webhooks which are related to erasure, don't trigger after 4 days. What is the reason? Is there any different method for receiving erasure webhooks?

Comment: Which framework you are using to develop the app? many frameworks blocks cross-domain requests. another thing you can do is please check webhook is set properly with a proper address by making API call with the GET method to /admin/webhooks.json endpoint

Comment: @BhargavKaklotara I'm using Node.JS . My app is using other webhooks like order update and it's working fine, even one of GDPR mandatory webhooks is working fine.

Comment: Hello @samurai_code,
I am getting the same issue "Shop data erasure endpoint
" is not fire when the user uninstalls my app. did you get solution ?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Shopify documentation](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/add-gdpr-webhooks-to-your-app):

> **customers/redact**
>
> When a store owner requests deletion of data on behalf of a customer, Shopify sends a payload on the customers/redact
>   topic to the apps installed on that store. If the customer hasn't
>   placed an order in the past six months, then Shopify sends the payload
>   10 days after their request. Otherwise, the the request will be
>   withheld until 6 months have passed.

The quickest seems to be to test with a user that did not order anything.

> **shop/redact**
>
> 48 hours after a store owner uninstalls your app, Shopify sends you a shop/redact webhook

Make sure you uninstall the app.

Comment: When I uninstalled app, it didn't trigger even after 4 days.